# Syntax of keys on keyboard in documentation

Tags: key-bindings, keyword

What is the meaning of `<S-x>` or `<C-x>` in the documentation? Example: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%3CS-Right%3E

I often see people using `<C-x>` to refer to Ctrl-x, but I don't believe that's what the documentation means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:help <s-`

```
<S-...>     shift-key           *shift* *<S-*
<C-...>     control-key         *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
```

Thus, `S-` refers to the holding the shift key while pressing the following key.  This is usually not necessary since `<s-a>` literally means `A`, but it is with `<s-left>` and `<s-right>`.

Answer (score 2):

`:help key-notation` shows a complete list of all special keys.